# How can I sort images by date or folder name from CameraRoll in React Native

Tags: react-native, camera-roll

I'm trying to make custom listView of camera roll in React Native.
And I see when I do ' CameraRoll.getPhotos(fetchParams) ', I can put some params. But there's no option for sorting or I can get the folders name.

Thanks in advance for the advice !

> In CameraRoll.js below..

```
var getPhotosParamChecker = createStrictShapeTypeChecker({
  /**
   * The number of photos wanted in reverse order of the photo application
   * (i.e. most recent first for SavedPhotos).
   */
  first: ReactPropTypes.number.isRequired,

  /**
   * A cursor that matches `page_info { end_cursor }` returned from a previous
   * call to `getPhotos`
   */
  after: ReactPropTypes.string,

  /**
   * Specifies which group types to filter the results to.
   */
  groupTypes: ReactPropTypes.oneOf(GROUP_TYPES_OPTIONS),

  /**
   * Specifies filter on group names, like 'Recent Photos' or custom album
   * titles.
   */
  groupName: ReactPropTypes.string,

  /**
  * Specifies filter on asset type
  */
  assetType: ReactPropTypes.oneOf(ASSET_TYPE_OPTIONS),

  /**
   * Filter by mimetype (e.g. image/jpeg).
   */
  mimeTypes: ReactPropTypes.arrayOf(ReactPropTypes.string),
});
```

It seems there is no way other then need to fix..
Or can I make a list of Image folders?

Comment: Do you found any solution?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Please sort according to time stamp. Above attached picture is the output of CameraRoll